# What can we say about a function $g$ if we know${f \over f + g} \to 1$?

Tags: functions, soft-question

This question came to me thinking about the prime counting function, $\pi (x)$. It is known that ${\pi(x) \over \text{li}(x)} \to 1$ but this does not imply $\pi(x) - \text{li}(x) \to 0$. I asked a question similar to this before, about two sequences which we could show easily also share this property, and the answer was ${n \over n + \sqrt{n}} \to 1, \ \ (n) - (n + \sqrt{n}) \to -\infty$. What can we say about sequences like this in general? My guess is that if two functions $f$, $h$ such that ${f \over h} \to 1$, then $h = f + g$, and ${f \over f + g} \to 1 \iff g' \lt f' \ \ \forall x\to \infty$. But I'm not sure if this is the case. What can we say about $g$ if this is all we know?

Comment: $\frac f{f+g}=\frac 1 {1+\frac g f} \to 1$, thus $\frac g f\to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\frac{f}{f+g}\to 1$ then $1+\frac{g}{f}=\frac{f+g}{f}\to 1.$ Thus, one has that $$\frac{g}{f}\to 0.$$